# When should I use .Count() and .Count in the context of an IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, collections

I'm aware that `.Count()` is an extension method in LINQ, and that fundamentally it uses the `.Count`, so I'm wondering, when should I use `Count()` and when should I use `.Count`? Is `.Count()` predominately better saved for queryable collections that are yet to be executed, and therefore don't have an enumeration yet? Am I *safer* simply always using `.Count()` extension method, or vice versa for the property? Or is this solely conditional depending on the collection?

Any advice, or articles, are greatly appreciated.

### Update 1

After decompiling the `.Count()` extension method in LINQ it appears to be using the `.Count` **property** if the `IEnumerable<T>` is an `ICollection<T>` or `ICollection`, which is what most answers have suggested. The only real overhead now that I can see is the  additional null and type checks, which isn't huge I suppose, but could still make a small amount of difference if performance were of the utmost importance.

Here's the decompiled LINQ `.Count()` extension method in .NET 4.0.

```
public static int Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }

    ICollection<TSource> collection = source as ICollection<TSource>;
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Count;
    }

    ICollection collection2 = source as ICollection;
    if (collection2 != null)
    {
        return collection2.Count;
    }

    int num = 0;
    checked
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                num++;
            }
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The extension method works on any `IEnumerable<T>` but it is costly because it counts the sequence by iterating it. There is an optimization if the sequence is `ICollection<T>` meaning that the length of the collection is known. Then the `Count` property is used but that is an implementation detail.

The best advice is to use the `Count` property if available for performance reasons.

> Is .Count() predominately better saved for queryable collections that are yet to be executed, and therefore don't have an enumeration yet?

If your collection is `IQueryable<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>` then the query provider may be able to return the count in some efficient maner. In that case you will not suffer a performance penalty but it depends on the query provider.

An `IQueryable<T>` will not have a `Count` property so there is no choice between using the extension method and the property. However, if you query provider does not provide an efficient way of computing `Count()` you might consider using `.ToList()` to pull the collection to the client side. It really depends on how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Count() when all you have is an interface that doesn't expose a Count or Length property, such as `IEnumerabe<T>`.

If you're dealing with a collection or collection interface (such as `List<T>` or `ICollection`) then you can simply use the Count property, likewise if you have an array use the Length property.

The implementation of the Count() extension property will use the underlying collection's `Count` property if it is available. Otherwise the collection will be enumerated to calculate the count.

Answer (score 1):

Count retrieves the property from a List (already calculated). Count() is an aggregation, like Sum(), Average(), etc. What it does is to count the items in the enumerable (I believe it internally uses the Count property if the enumerable is a list).

This is an example of the concrete use of the Count() method, when it doesn't just use the Count property:

```
var list = new List {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

var count = list.Where(x => x > 5).Count();
```

Also, Count() has an overload that will count the items matching the predicate:

```
var count = list.Count(x => x > 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with comments of `.Count` if it is available (i.e. an object that implements `ICollection<T>` under the bonnet).

But they are wrong about `.Count()` being 'costly'.  `Enumerable.Count()` will check if the object implements `ICollection<T>.Count` before it enumerates the elements and count them.

I.e. something like,

```
public int Enumerable.Count<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    var collection = source as ICollection
    if (collection != null)
    {
        return collection.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that's what it does internally (I'm not sure)

Comment: Wow, I don't know what game is my brain playing, I didn't read that part!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it matters since Count() probably just reads the Count property.  The performance difference is truly negligible. Use whichever you like.  I use Count() when possible just to be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, if you have an `ICollection<T>`, use the Count property.

I would suggest that the `IEnumerable.Count()` method is really intended for use when the **only** thing you want to do with the elements of an enumeration is count them.  The equivalent of SQL "SELECT COUNT(...".

If in addition you want to do something else with the elements of an enumeration, it makes more sense to generate a collection (usually a list using `ToList()`), then you can use the Count property and do whatever else you want to do.